# Reviewing Suggested Edits

Tags: support, feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits, 10k-tools

As part of the mod tools, there is a tool to review and approve suggested edits. The "review suggested edits" shows something like below which is not of much help to review and approve the edit.

[image]

It makes more sense, especially on math.se, to show the final form of the post, including the typeset i.e the form it would appear on screen once it has been posted/approved.

This is of more relevance to math.se since most of suggested edits have got to do with some typesetting changes. It is hard to figure out what exactly the changes are and how they affect the post without looking at how they appear on the screen.

Comment: Two work-arounds: (a) click on the "improve" button, which will bring up a normal editing screen and you can read the final forms. Downside is that then the edit will appear to be from you and not the person who proposed the edit. (b) If you are sure that the edits are only about math display and not about content, then click approve, navigate to the question, and read it over to see if you "really" approve.

Comment: @Willie: My impression was that if you make no changes in the "improve" screen, it actually does not let you implement the edit from there (so there is no danger of the edit being incorrectly attributed); hence in my answer below I suggested pressing the back button and using the "approve" button.

Comment: and (c) undergo intensive training with Knuth or Lamport in the secluded mountains of California for 3 months thereby acquiring the secret skill of parsing (La)TeX _in your head_. =p

Comment: @Willie: Another way to master that is to write the macros and their output on the bottom of beer mugs. This is a great way to train, since you engrave the compilation into your subconscious!

Comment: I don't think this can be changed at the math.se level; but perhaps you can ask in meta.stackoverflow for a change, perhaps a link to a "Preview changes" like Wikipedia has.

Comment: @Arturo: I posted on meta.stackoverflow few minutes back http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103018/reviewing-suggested-edits

Comment: @Asaf Ah, so that explains why the swag mug design is taking so long...

Comment: @Sivaram: Well, it got closed as a duplicate, even though it was by no means a duplicate of the indicated post: you weren't complaining that there was "too much noise", you were asking for *more* stuff to be put there, in a way.

Comment: This is very interesting. There *is* an option, when reviewing suggested edits, to show the "actual" posts rather than the markdown differences. However, because of how the diff engine identifies and renders changes, it causes breaks in the MathJax that results in actual changes to the TeX not being displayed as their final result. Compare [markdown diff](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MgsRt.png) with [final diff](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MSOwj.png), it's quite odd. I'll see if anyone knows if this can be altered in any fashion.

Answer (score 9):

I had also been quite annoyed by this aspect of reviewing proposed edits. However, one solution  is to click the "improve" button, which  will show you exactly what you want (what the end result of the proposed edit would look like), and then if it is satisfactory, just hit the "back" button and approve it.

Comment: @Willie: Yes. I have been doing what you and Zev have suggested. But am finding it increasing annoying.

Comment: @Siv: I agree that it would be a good feature to have. Hence my comments are mere workarounds, not real answers.

Comment: +1: This is what I always do, and I am used to it now (I used to find it annoying at some point in the past).

Comment: I do that, but I'm slow and I often find that somebody's already approved it once I hit Back... :D

Answer (score 6):

Well, not an entire solution, but simply click the small icon on the left to show the post in pure markup without rendering:

[image]

Comment: I just tried that. It doesn't actually help since the changed $\LaTeX$ is not compiled.

Comment: yes, it is at best a minor workaround for now

Answer (score 5):

Starting earlier today, we now treat formulas as single units when it comes to comparing them between revisions. The inline and side-by-side views show rendered formulas, and the "side-by-side markdown" view can be used to view the actual notation changes.

Inline:

> [image]

Side-by-side:

> [image]

Side-by-side markdown:

> [image]