# MathJax rendering error in Review | Suggested Edits?

Tags: bug, mathjax, review, suggested-edits

Sometimes I edit a question to format the MathJax correctly. I submit the edit, and everything looks good. I get the notification "Thanks for your edit! This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed." But then when I click the "peer reviewed" link it displays my edit incorrectly. Here is an example of how my edit displays for me:
[image]

But the review tab shows this:
[image]

If this is how my edit is rendered for anyone reviewing it, then this might cause users to reject my edit based on false information. Has anyone else experienced this issue? The only post I can find with the same issue is [this one](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2809/reviewing-suggested-edits). The answers to that post suggest some workarounds, but I still don't understand why it has a hard time rendering such a simple edit. That question was posted over 6 years ago. Is this issue getting the attention it deserves?

Comment: This came up pretty recently. The target is not strictly about suggested edits, but the basic problems seem to be exactly the same.